# Two-dimensional list in Python?

Tags: python, list

So I have this code:

```
Team1 = ["Red", 10]
Team2 = ["Green", 5]
Team3 = ["Blue", 6]
Team4 = ["Yellow", 8]
Team5 = ["Purple", 9]
Team6 = ["Brown", 4]

TeamList = [Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4, Team5, Team6]
```

I want to make a two-dimensional list of difference in scores between each pair of teams.
The output can be like this:
[image: Output]

What is the easiest way to do this? Thanks :)

Comment: This would be a good homework assignment

Comment: Shouldn't all differences be positive? abs(team1-team2) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using tabs rather than any fancy formatting to build the chart:

```
Team1 = ["Red", 10]
Team2 = ["Green", 5]
Team3 = ["Blue", 6]
Team4 = ["Yellow", 8]
Team5 = ["Purple", 9]
Team6 = ["Brown", 4]

TeamList = [Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4, Team5, Team6]

# print the top row of team names, tab separated, starting two tabs over:
print '\t\t', '\t'.join(team[0] for team in TeamList)

# for each row in the chart
for team in TeamList:
    # put two tabs between each score difference column
    scoreline = '\t\t'.join(str(team[1] - other[1]) for other in TeamList)
    # and print the team name, a tab, then the score columns
    print team[0], '\t', scoreline
```

Comment: Alternately, string formatting using fixed-width fields for the text. (Honk if you love `sprintf()`.)

Answer (score 6):

You could try:

```
[[x[1]-y[1] for y in TeamList] for x in TeamList]
```

That will generate a nested list representing the proposed output (without the column and row headings, of course).

Comment: The OP seems new to Python, so I'd introduce the "simpler" version of `for` before this

Comment: @Kshitij This way is objectively simpler. It is only because of your familiarity with other programming languages that you think otherwise.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel but it also introduces lambda definitions with unnatural scopes. While most experienced python programmers love one-liners like this one (myself included), I believe it could confuse newcomers to the language. Of course, that's just my opinion.

Comment: What's unnatural about the scope here? What has this got to do with `lambda`? It means exactly what it says: a list of (each list of the results of `x[1] - y[1]` for each `y` value) for each `x` value.

Answer (score 3):

You could try nested for loop. Something like this:-

```
for team1 in TeamList:
    for team2 in TeamList:
        print team1[1]-team2[1]
```

This will give the score difference. The output will have to be formatted to get the exact table look that you want.

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension would work (but nested list comprehensions don't sit quite right with me.) `itertools.product()` is another way.

Consider the following as food for thought:

```
import itertools

scores = {
"Red"   : 10,
"Green" : 5,
"Blue"  : 6,
"Yellow": 8,
"Purple": 9,
"Brown" : 4,
}

for team_1, team_2 in itertools.product(scores, scores):
    print ("Team 1 [%s] scored %i, Team 2 [%s] scored %i." % (team_1, scores[team_1], team_2, scores[team_2]) )
```

Which outputs:

```
Team 1 [Blue] scored 6, Team 2 [Blue] scored 6.
Team 1 [Blue] scored 6, Team 2 [Brown] scored 4.
... (32 more lines) ...
Team 1 [Red] scored 10, Team 2 [Green] scored 5.
Team 1 [Red] scored 10, Team 2 [Red] scored 10.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Team1 = ["Red", 10]
Team2 = ["Green", 5]
Team3 = ["Blue", 6]
Team4 = ["Yellow", 8]
Team5 = ["Purple", 9]
Team6 = ["Brown", 4]

TeamList = [Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4, Team5, Team6]

# calculate scores
scores = [[x[1]-y[1] for y in TeamList] for x in TeamList]

# print the top row of team names, tab separated, starting two tabs over:
print('\t\t', '\t'.join(team[0] for team in TeamList))

# for each row in the chart
for score, team in zip(scores,TeamList):
    print(("%s"+"\t%s"*len(TeamList)) % ((team[0],)+tuple(score)))
```